# To Sort a List <KeyValuePair<int,string>> by key in c sharp

Tags: c#

I have a directory which contains multiple sql files in the following format

```
1_aaaaa.sql
2_ddddd.sql
.
.
.
```

I need to to get those files in the increasing order..

I have written the following program:

```
if (Directory.Exists(DatabaseLocation))
{

     DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(DatabaseLocation);
     var files = dir.GetFiles("*.sql");
     List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> listFiles = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
     foreach (var file in files)
     {
         listFiles.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(int.Parse(file.Name.Split('_')[0]),file.FullName));

      }
      listFiles.OrderBy(x =>x.Key);
}
```

This gives me the wrong result. Sequence which i get from this is

```
10....
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
1
20
21

and so on...
```

however i want the following order:

```
1
2
3
4
....
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you ever find yourself in that situation?  Why wouldn't you be using a `SortedList` in the first place?

Comment: i also need to retain the sequence in which files were being fetched. It would be difficult to get that sequence using sortedlist.

Answer (score 4):

Use following code:

```
listFiles=listFiles.OrderBy(x =>x.Key).ToList();
```